# Load test performance counters using Visual Studio Online in Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, web, load-testing

I have Visual Studio Online which I use to run load tests against a remote web app (this app  is not hosted within Azure).

What would be the best way to gather performance stats from the load test?

Comment: What performance statistics do you want?

Answer (score 0):

The default will collect test durations, transaction times and page load times. With Visual Studio Online you cannot collect performance data from the various servers for the website.

If you run the load test on your own computers, including computers in the cloud (but not Visual Studio Online) then you can collect the above plus any counter that the Windows PerfMon can see. You may need to sort out permissions etc to make the server's counters visible to the computer running the load test.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please go through the below link and let me know if this is what you are looking for?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/07/get-application-performance-data-during-load-runs-with-visual-studio-online.aspx

Little additional information
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/04/cloud-load-testing-with-visual-studio-online-launching-general-availability.aspx